# Is this transmission fluid level too high?

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, corolla, transmission-fluid

I had the transmission fluid changed at the dealership (non flush). On my 2013 Corolla.

This is after driving 30 min on hot engine with it running. Is this level too high?

[image]

[image]

---

**Update: Here are new pictures where I tried it again. This is after 45 minutes of driving, engine running in park, in a level parking lot:**

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It really depends, but it definitely *could be over full*.

The reason I say "it depends" is, how did you take the fluid reading? Follow these simple guidelines to see if you've gone wrong:

1. Ensure the engine/transmission is fully warm (which you did by driving 30 minutes).
2. Ensure your vehicle is on level ground when checking.
3. When you pull the dipstick, wipe it off with a rag first off, then restab the dipstick into the tube fully, then pull it right back out to check the level.

Step #3 ensures you are getting the "now" reading and not splash up which may have occurred during use. It will leave a more defined line on the dipstick that way as well. What you are showing in the pictures leads me to believe you may not have done this when checking.

If after checking the dipstick following these guidelines, the level still shows high, take it back to the dealership and tell them it's overfilled. This is *very important* because too much fluid in the transmission can cause it to blow seals due to over pressure. While the seals themselves are not terribly expensive, where they reside costs a lot in labor to replace them.

Comment: Your owners manual may have a procedure for checking the fluid level.  The procedure for my particular car differs from Paulster2's answer.

Comment: As the comments point out methods of checking the level - some require cycling through the gears etc

Comment: @dman Unless you know the transmission temperature on newer cars it can be hard to tell what the correct level is. On non-CVT AT Toyota's the hot range is 70-80°C or 158-176°F. You also need to move the gear selector through all positions before checking.

Comment: Transmission seals would only blow out if the vent is plugged. The problem with overfilled transmissions is when the fluid starts getting churned by the gear train and it gets aerated. Not good.

Comment: @Tequilaman - Too much fluid = Too much pressure. Over filling can and will blow seals. This is with or with out a good vent. This is the main reason every automatic transmission I've ever dealt with says "Do not overfill". You'd have to add *a lot* of fluid over the full mark for it to get to the point where it's getting directly churned by the gear train.

Comment: @Paulster2 I have been in the transmission industry for over 20 years. I have run quality control departments and done process development for major remanufactures. I have rebuilt and diagnosed thousands of transmissions. The reason every transmission says "Do not overfill." is because they are engineered to run with a specific level of fluid. Yes, overfilling causes problems.Blowing seals is not one of them. If you get a leaking seal, then you have a bad seal, worn bushing or bearing being the seal, or a hydraulic problem. The vent keeps the unit from having pressure build up. Period.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I meet items #1 and  #2 in your list. On item #3, I took several stabbings over and over trying to get a hard line. I would use new a blue shop paper towel and did it real slowly to avoid splash. Each time I got what you see.  I updated the post with the new pics. Should I be concerned? Or should there be a harder edge line to tell?